# Bringing my obj from Blender into DAZ manually creates some weird issues

Tags: modeling

Edit: Is there just a simple, to the point, checklist for steps to check your mesh before importing into DAZ for prop creation?

I can't get any more specific about what's going on than below because I have no idea what happened except things went badly. If no one can answer me, I understand.

My latest project is me trying to gain a bit more skill kinetically. I got a pair of MR pants and set about  making them my own.

Things were going great for a while, but suddenly things were not so great. Morphs melted. The faces suddenly were facing the wrong way. The last weirdness was when I tried to convert to subD in DAZ, and things suddenly were no longer symmetrized.

I've checked and rechecked the mesh in Blender I dunno how many times. I think most of my problem is I don't know exactly WHAT to check? Yes, there are a lot of discussions out there. I'm aging. I want everyone off my lawn. Is there just a simple, to the point, checklist? (Yes, I've spent some time looking. But when you aren't sure of what you're looking for, you won't know it when you find it.) A checklist is a good point to not only get it done, but learn from. Tried and true. (hoping) I did find mention of a check tool, but tbh I wouldn't want that just yet.

So far I've checked for islands, told the system to delete loose, symmetrized (and now the topo looks kinda strange), uv mapped (which annoyingly the geo surface set up always gets lost going from one to the other), and banged my head on my desk.

For a while things were amazing. About 2/3 of the way done, and I'm not sure what happened. One of the morphs brought in a weird shape on the thigh and it all went downhill from there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Also some images and the export format you're using might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Spear Carrier, welcome.  I think you'll attract better answers here on BSE with a terse, focused, technical description of the problem. Please include an illustration of 'morphing',  'melting', and any settings that may help us, including export format, as suggested.

Comment: HI guys. I'd be more specific if I knew how. "Is there a checklist for checking your mesh?" is the meat of it.

I went back to an earlier mesh before going to bed. Too soon to screenshot any new problems.